# How to change the editor in a QTreeView column in order to change the value with a QComboBox?

Tags: qt, delegates, qtreeview, qcombobox, pyside6

I created a `QTreeView` to show you my problem. Most of the code comes from there : [editable tree model](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_widgets_itemviews_editabletreemodel.html). So if you have any question that concerns the model, go check this first link.
Now let me explain the problem : I would like to populate the `QTreeView` with my database. In the third column, you can see 'Types' of items. I would like the `QCombobox` to be, by default, equal to those types. Moreover, I want to get a `signal` and the `value`, when a `QCombobox` is changed in my `model` in order to update the value in my Database. Here is the [minimal reproductible exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication,QComboBox
import os
import sys

import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtCore import (QAbstractItemModel, QItemSelectionModel,
                            QModelIndex, Qt, Slot)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QAbstractItemView, QMainWindow, QTreeView,
                               QWidget)
from PySide6.QtTest import QAbstractItemModelTester



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(573, 468)

        self.view = QTreeView()
        self.view.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.view.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectItems)
        self.view.setHorizontalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
        self.view.setAnimated(False)
        self.view.setAllColumnsShowFocus(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        file_menu = menubar.addMenu("&File")
        self.exit_action = file_menu.addAction("E&xit")
        self.exit_action.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)


        self.setWindowTitle("Editable Tree Model")

        headers = ["number", "value",'Type']

        self.model = TreeModel(headers, self)

        if "-t" in sys.argv:
            QAbstractItemModelTester(self.model, self)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.expandAll()

        qindex_widget = self.view.model().index(0,1,QModelIndex())
        a = 0
        while qindex_widget.isValid() :
            combobox = QComboBox()
            combobox.addItems(['len','diam','concent'])

            qindex_widget = self.view.model().index(a,1,QModelIndex())
            self.view.setIndexWidget(qindex_widget,combobox)
            a += 1
        self.view.model().dataChanged.connect(self.onDataChanged)
        for column in range(self.model.columnCount()):
            self.view.resizeColumnToContents(column)

    def onDataChanged(self) :
        print('Data changed')


class TreeItem:
    def __init__(self, data: list, parent: 'TreeItem' = None):
        self.item_data = data
        self.parent_item = parent
        self.child_items = []

    def child(self, number: int) -> 'TreeItem':
        if number < 0 or number >= len(self.child_items):
            return None
        return self.child_items[number]

    def last_child(self):
        return self.child_items[-1] if self.child_items else None

    def child_count(self) -> int:
        return len(self.child_items)

    def child_number(self) -> int:
        if self.parent_item:
            return self.parent_item.child_items.index(self)
        return 0

    def column_count(self) -> int:
        return len(self.item_data)

    def data(self, column: int):
        if column < 0 or column >= len(self.item_data):
            return None
        return self.item_data[column]

    def insert_children(self, position: int, count: int, columns: int) -> bool:
        if position < 0 or position > len(self.child_items):
            return False

        for row in range(count):
            data = [None] * columns
            item = TreeItem(data.copy(), self)
            self.child_items.insert(position, item)

        return True

    def insert_columns(self, position: int, columns: int) -> bool:
        if position < 0 or position > len(self.item_data):
            return False

        for column in range(columns):
            self.item_data.insert(position, None)

        for child in self.child_items:
            child.insert_columns(position, columns)

        return True

    def parent(self):
        return self.parent_item

    def remove_children(self, position: int, count: int) -> bool:
        if position < 0 or position + count > len(self.child_items):
            return False

        for row in range(count):
            self.child_items.pop(position)

        return True

    def remove_columns(self, position: int, columns: int) -> bool:
        if position < 0 or position + columns > len(self.item_data):
            return False

        for column in range(columns):
            self.item_data.pop(position)

        for child in self.child_items:
            child.remove_columns(position, columns)

        return True

    def set_data(self, column: int, value):
        if column < 0 or column >= len(self.item_data):
            return False

        self.item_data[column] = value
        return True

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        result = f"<treeitem.TreeItem at 0x{id(self):x}"
        for d in self.item_data:
            result += f' "{d}"' if d else " <None>"
        result += f", {len(self.child_items)} children>"
        return result


class TreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):

    def __init__(self, headers: list, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.root_data = headers
        self.root_item = TreeItem(self.root_data.copy())
        self.setup_model_data(self.root_item)

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = None) -> int:
        return self.root_item.column_count()

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = None):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        if role != Qt.DisplayRole and role != Qt.EditRole:
            return None

        item: TreeItem = self.get_item(index)

        return item.data(index.column())

    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.ItemFlags:
        if not index.isValid():
            return Qt.NoItemFlags

        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | QAbstractItemModel.flags(self, index)

    def get_item(self, index: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()) -> TreeItem:
        if index.isValid():
            item: TreeItem = index.internalPointer()
            if item:
                return item

        return self.root_item

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation,
                   role: int = Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.root_item.data(section)

        return None

    def index(self, row: int, column: int, parent: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()) -> QModelIndex:
        if parent.isValid() and parent.column() != 0:
            return QModelIndex()

        parent_item: TreeItem = self.get_item(parent)
        if not parent_item:
            return QModelIndex()

        child_item: TreeItem = parent_item.child(row)
        if child_item:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, child_item)
        return QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, index: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()) -> QModelIndex:
        if not index.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()

        child_item: TreeItem = self.get_item(index)
        if child_item:
            parent_item: TreeItem = child_item.parent()
        else:
            parent_item = None

        if parent_item == self.root_item or not parent_item:
            return QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parent_item.child_number(), 0, parent_item)
    
    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()) -> int:
        if parent.isValid() and parent.column() > 0:
            return 0

        parent_item: TreeItem = self.get_item(parent)
        if not parent_item:
            return 0
        return parent_item.child_count()

    def setData(self, index: QModelIndex, value, role: int) -> bool:
        if role != Qt.EditRole:
            return False

        item: TreeItem = self.get_item(index)
        result: bool = item.set_data(index.column(), value)

        if result:
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole])

        return result

    def setHeaderData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, value,
                      role: int = None) -> bool:
        if role != Qt.EditRole or orientation != Qt.Horizontal:
            return False

        result: bool = self.root_item.set_data(section, value)

        if result:
            self.headerDataChanged.emit(orientation, section, section)

        return result

    def setup_model_data(self, parent: TreeItem):
        parents = [parent]
        Data = [[0,1,'diam'],[1,0.6,'len'],[2,1.9,'conc'],[3,4.5,'diam'],[4,0.022,'len']]
        for item in Data :
            parent : TreeItem = parents[0]
            col_count = self.root_item.column_count()
            parent.insert_children(parent.child_count(), 1, col_count)
            column_data = [item[0],item[1],item[2]]

            for column in range(len(column_data)):
                child = parent.last_child()
                child.set_data(column, column_data[column])

    def _repr_recursion(self, item: TreeItem, indent: int = 0) -> str:
        result = " " * indent + repr(item) + "\n"
        for child in item.child_items:
            result += self._repr_recursion(child, indent + 2)
        return result

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self._repr_recursion(self.root_item)
    


if __name__=="__main__" :
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I read different topics on stackoverflow, but I didn't figure out how to do this.

Do you have any ideas ? Thanks

**Edit :**

Ok, I found the answers to my question. I created a `customDelegate` to modify the data as I want to. Here is the code to do so :

```py
class CustomDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index : QModelIndex):
        if index.column() == 0 :
            editor = QLineEdit(parent)
            return editor
        

        if index.column() == 2 :
            combo = QComboBox(parent)
            combo.addItems(["Lenght","Diametre","Coax"])
            editor = combo
            
            return editor
        
        if index.column() > 4 and index.column() :
            editor = CustomDoubleSpinbox(parent)
            editor.setDecimals(3)
            return editor
```

Usually, modfying a data is done thanks to a `QLineEdit` or a `QDoubleSpinBox` but as you can see, you can choose for each column what king of editor you want. I hope it helped you as it helped me ! Bye